# How to design a rest api using akka-http so that it is easy to test?

Tags: scala, oop, testing, functional-programming, akka-http

I have a simple REST-API. Each api sub-path has its own service implementation.

The question is: how to correctly test it?

Example:

```
class RestAPI(implicit dispatcher: ExecutionContext)  // some services need its own dispatcher
extends FirstService with SecondService with etc... { 
  val api: Route = pathPrefix("api") {
    get {
      firstService()
    } ~ post {
      secondService()
    } ~ ...
  }

  def start(implicit system: ActorSystem, materializer: ActorMaterializer): Unit = {
    Http().bindAndHandle(api, "host", 8080)
  }
}

object RestAPI {
  def apply(implicit dispatcher: ExecutionContext): RestAPI = new RestAPI
}
```

In this case i cannot test my endpoint because of dependency of execution context and service implementation which i should mock. I can create my own implementation of RestApi in  test case, but i have to update it each time a change something inside real RestApi

I tried another way:

```
class RestAPI(implicit dispatcher: ExecutionContext)  { // some services need its own dispatcher
  this: FirstService with SecondService with etc... =>
  val api: Route = pathPrefix("api") {
    get {
      firstService()
    } ~ post {
      secondService()
    } ~ ...
  }

  def start(implicit system: ActorSystem, materializer: ActorMaterializer): Unit = {
    Http().bindAndHandle(api, "host", 8080)
  }
}

object RestAPI {
  def apply(implicit dispatcher: ExecutionContext): RestAPI = new RestAPI extends DefaultFirstService with DefaultSecondService with etc...
}


Test {
  val api = (new RestApi(dispatcher) extends StubOne with StubTwo with ...).api
}
```

In this case, at least, i can test all endpoints but i have to pass execution context and build RestApi object before i can get my routes. Also, this is not the best solution because of now i need to write this `new RestApi(dispatcher) extends StubOne with StubTwo with ...` and if there is 1 or 2 services - this is ok, but if there is more than 3, than it looks a bit awkward (in my opion).

Than i tried this approach:

```
class RestAPI(serviceOne: FirstService, serviceTwo: SecondService, ...)(implicit dispatcher: ExecutionContext)  { // some services need its own dispatcher
  val api: Route = pathPrefix("api") {
    get {
      serviceOne.firstService()
    } ~ post {
      serviceTwo.secondService()
    } ~ ...
  }

  def start(implicit system: ActorSystem, materializer: ActorMaterializer): Unit = {
    Http().bindAndHandle(api, "host", 8080)
  }
}

object RestAPI {
  def apply(serviceOne: FirstService, serviceTwo: SecondService, ...)(implicit dispatcher: ExecutionContext): RestAPI = new RestAPI(serviceOne, serviceTwo, ...)
}


Test {
  val api = (new RestApi(...)(dispatcher)).api
}
```

Probably, it is the most common approach, but i still have to pass execution context.

So, the main question is how to test my endpoints which depend on service implementation but without real implementation of those services? I suspect that there is a problem in implementation design but i can still change it.  The question it: which approach i should to choose?

Comment: Wiremock is your best friend here. Mockito could also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need the execution context to run `Http().bindAndHandle(api, "host", 8080)`, so I would just do that in a different class.

If you do that, you can use your approach #3, use [mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala) to provide mocks of your dependencies and once you have a fully constructed instance of `RestAPI`, just pass it to wherever you had moved the http binding code to and thats it.

So to sum up, separate the API definition from the Http Server initialisation, mock your dependencies and be happy!